# HTML alignment clarification

Tags: html, css

This function results in a user picture (user.jpg) and user's profile description (stripslashes($row[1])) to be displayed.

Right now, the picture is to the left of the user's profile description .

How can I make the user's profile description appear below the picture?

```
function showProfile($user)
{
    if (file_exists("$user.jpg"))
        echo "<img src='{$user}.jpg?".time()."' align='left' />";

    $result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=both /><br />";
    }
}
```

Here is my css file:

```
/* styles.css */

* {
    font-family:verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size  :14pt; }

body {
     width     :700px;
    background:#fff;
    }

html {
    background:#fff }

img {
    border            :1px solid black;
    margin-bottom     :50px;
    margin-right      :15px;
     -moz-box-shadow   :2px 2px 2px #888;
     -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #888;
     box-shadow        :2px 2px 2px #888; } 

li a, .button{
    text-decoration:none; }

li a:hover, .button:hover {
    color:green; }

.appname {
    text-align :center;
    background :#c4c4c4;
    color      :#40d;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size  :20pt;
    padding    :4px; }

.fieldname {
    float:left;
    width:120px; }

.main {
    margin-left:40px; }

.info {
    background :lightgreen;
    color      :blue;
     border     :1px solid green;
     padding    :5px 10px;
    margin-left:40px; }

.menu li, .button {
    display           :inline;
    padding           :4px 6px;
    border            :1px solid #777;
    background        :#ddd;
     color             :#d04;
    margin-right      :8px;
     border-radius     :5px;
     -moz-box-shadow   :2px 2px 2px #888;
     -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #888;
     box-shadow        :2px 2px 2px #888; }

.subhead {
    font-weight:bold; }

.taken, .error {
    color:red; }

.available {
    color:green; }

.whisper {
    font-style:italic;
    color     :#006600; }
```

Comment: Can you just wrap everything in a `div` and style it accordingly?

Comment: Since it isn't a php issue, please show the produced html and css instead.

Comment: There are dozens of possible solutions, but it's impossible to determine which ones are right in this situation, without seeing at least some HTML and CSS. `clear=both` on the `br` tag suggests all kinds of floating elements, so we need that context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style="float:left;clear:both;"` in  your `<img />` instead of setting the `align` property.

```
function showProfile($user)
{
if (file_exists("$user.jpg"))
    echo "<img src='{$user}.jpg?".time()."' style='float:left;clear:both;' />";

$result = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo stripslashes($row[1]) . "<br clear=both /><br />";
}
}
```

Comment: That will only work if `img` is a floating block element. By default that is not the case.

Comment: @GolezTrol ah, good point.  updated answer.  This should work for `inline-block` too pending the `white-space` declaration, whether specified or by default.  Thanks!